# Drawing correct CALayer colors honoring NSAppearance

Tags: macos, calayer, nswindow, theming

I am looking into theming my app by setting `window.appearance`.
In my app, I draw some stuff inside layers. I also use Core Plot, which renders its charts in layers.

For the default aqua appearance, I just use the system colors (such as `NSColor.textColor` and `NSColor.gridColor`) and they are drawn in the correct color in `CALayer`. But changing the window's appearance to vibrant dark causes colors to be drawn incorrectly.

`Is there any way to obtain the correct color for a given`NSAppearance? Private API is acceptable too.

---

If the question is not clear, here is a very simple example to show the problem.

I set up a `CATextLayer` that is added as a sublayer of the main view's sublayers and an `NSTextFied` that is added as a subview:

```
CATextLayer* textLayer = [CATextLayer new];
textLayer.string = @"Is this colored correctly? (Layer)";
textLayer.foregroundColor = NSColor.textColor.CGColor;
textLayer.contentsScale = 2.0;
textLayer.frame = (CGRect){0,0, [textLayer preferredFrameSize]};

NSTextField* textField = [NSTextField new];
textField.stringValue = @"Is this colored correctly? (View)";
textField.textColor = NSColor.textColor;
textField.font = (__bridge id)textLayer.font;
textField.editable = NO;
textField.selectable = NO;
textField.bezeled = NO;
textField.backgroundColor = nil;
[textField sizeToFit];
textField.frame = (CGRect){0, 60, textField.bounds.size};

[self.view.layer addSublayer:textLayer];
[self.view addSubview:textField];
```

On an Aqua window, both appear correctly:

[image]

However, on a dark vibrant window, the layer does not, while the text field does:

[image]

I'd like to know how to get the correct color for a given `NSAppearance`.

Comment: Can you be more specific or show an example of "changing the window's appearance to vibrant dark causes colors to be drawn incorrectly"?

Comment: Not sure what is not clear about the question, but I have added an example to demonstrate it better.

Comment: Is setting the text color manually depending on the window color not an option?

Comment: Obviously, it’s not optimal, and not what is being asked in the question. It may seem easy for text color (black vs white text color), but there are many system colors, which may change for each OS version. Additionally, there are vibrancy considerations.

Comment: I understand that, and I’ve encountered a similar situation before; in my case a simple invert did the trick in that circumstance, although it might not in yours.

Comment: The problem is colors like selection color, control background, etc are different colors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I had an incorrect approach.

The right way to do it, is to implement `-updateLayer` in the view and take the colors' `CGColor` snapshot there. `-updateLayer` is called when the appearance changes, so the view can update it with the correct color values.